# Specify a volume type on GKE when creating a PV

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

When creating a PV on GKE and applying the pv.yaml I get an error message:

```
The PersistentVolume "pv" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type
```

The pv.yaml is show as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - 'ReadWriteOnce'
  storageClassName: standard
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use PeristentVolumeClaims which provisions PersistentVolume for your automatically, this is called dynamic [provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#dynamic_provisioning).

You should manually provision PersistentVolume only if you want to link to an preexisting Persistent disk. Here is the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd) for more info